# How do I Fix designer when components are not showing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Yesterday I updated windows 10. Today when I opened visual studio it seems like .cs[design] is not working properly. All the components I used is aligned with same size and same margin.

I've tried to roll back some updates, except for those updates that required specific files('__vs' some thing like this).

I didn't change designer.cs or resx file.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Has the designer.cs file changed according to your source control system?

Comment: no nothing changed.. really nothing